# How to set up 301 redirect for changing blog URL structure

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Problem:

We're about to launch a 2.0 version of an existing website. Entirely new CMS, code, and design. Right now, there's tons of blog content (the core of the site) located at `domain.com/blog/`

Our URL structure is changing. The current site uses this structure `http://domain.com/blog/post/title-of-the-post` but the new site uses `http://domain.com/blog/title-of-the-post`. Notice, we've removed `/post` from the url structure to simplify things. All slugs (`title-of-the-post`) have remained in tact.

I need a .htaccess 301 redirect solution that ensures any time someone clicks a link to an old post, that the server redirects them to the new url with the simplified `/blog` only structure.

The Regex stuff I can online is entirely too complex for what I need and indecipherable for my lack of experience with the syntax.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So, you need to redirect from http://olddomain.com/blog/post/something to http://newdomain.com/blog/something ?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you need this rule: RewriteRule ^blog/post/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [R,NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from old url structure to new,  try one of the following in your old_domain/htaccess:

**mod_rewrite**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/post/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/blog/%1 [NC,L,R]
```

or

**mod_alias**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/post/([^/]+)/?$ http://newdomain.com/post/$1
```